# What is the regular expression to match a certain subdomain OR a certain folder?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a custom filter in Google Analytics. I want to only include traffic to one subdomain of our domain, OR traffic a folder on a different subdomain. For example:

`promotions.foo.com [match]

    www.foo.com/chocolate [match]

    funtime.foo.com [no match]

    www.foo.com/vanilla [no match]

    www.foo.com [no match]`

Is this type of matching possible with a regular expression?

Comment: what makes chocolate a match but vanilla not a match...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(promotions.foo.com(\/.*)?|www.foo.com\/chocolate)$`

It's tricky, since the domain is the same, one would be tempted to craft some clever regex that only mentions `foo.com` once. But this is the clearest solution.
Don't forget to escape the slash if needed (depends on the dialect).

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. I forgot to mention that I want to be able to capture traffic to ANY folder under promotions.foo.com, but only /chocolate under www. What would that look like? Regardless, I will accept your answer - thank so much.

Comment: @denverfone Thanks! Updated to include optional folders for promotions.foo.com